# Silverlight application hosted in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, session-state

I have hosted Silverlight application in ASP.Net page.

We make use of a WCF Service to update/bind data on the controls.

When we deployed the application on load balanced enviroment, it worked for all our test cases,even when tested for the same user in different machines.

Will it fail?

We haven't done any code changes when moving from single server to multiserver environment (yes the URLs for the service reference are the same after the load balancing - adding new servers).

Is it working because the client code is loaded on the browser machine and we don't need to perform session management?

Comment: It should work fine ..But be sure to test in exact enviornment before going to release it if you have some security concern.

Comment: I guess that your WCF service should be stateless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session state with a Silverlight application is a little magical. Usually, in ASP.Net the session state is stored in the browser and submitted with the form; it is retransmitted each time the form is submitted.

Since Silverlight doesn't do form submits (it can, but noone ever uses it that way) - it goes through WCF/RIA - the session state is loaded once and maintained in the browser, allowing the Silverlight app to access it on demand.